# Document on recto page but numeration on both recto and verso

Tags: page-breaking, page-numbering, blank-page

Last month I met a friend of mine which was writing her master thesis (with Word) and she said me that her supervisor told her that the thesis must have been `oneside` but the numeration must have been `twoside`, so she was inserting *manually* about 170 `\clearpage`s (using LaTeX naming).

When I heard such a weird thing, I first opened my eyes wide, but after I thought "Hey, if she had written her thesis in LaTeX, some lines of code would suffice!". Some days ago I remembered that conversation and started search *which* lines of code are needed, and I couldn't find a solution.

Some TeXpert can help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}
     \null\clearpage
  \else
     \relax
  \fi
  }
\begin{document}
   \kant[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great! I didn't know the `atbegshi` package. I thought to redefine a macro that TeX calls when decides to break a page, but I was wondering *which* macro TeX calls. This is more elegant!

Comment: +1. A good example (thanks also to OP) why not Word.