# Separate input streams for recto and verso pages

Tags: page-breaking

This problem may be somewhat 'special'. I want to typeset a book with different inputs for recto and verso pages. The text should appear on the recto pages and images on the verso pages only (this works out as I do have approx. the same number of printed pages and images).

One approach I found so far was the reledmac/reledpar pair of packages, but I could not manage to obtain the required output. The idea was like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-5]

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart
     \kant[6-10]
   \pend
   \endnumbering  
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart
     \kant[11-15]
   \pend
   \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}

\end{document}
```

However, nothing happened (i.e., only kant1-5 were printed at all). I am not sure whether the reled* packages are the best approach. No synchronization of pages' content or paragraph numbering is required (in contrast to critical editions, for which reled* were designed).

I also found the atbegshi MWE (*), allowing to put the text on the recto pages as desired (it worked). But would this approach allow for inserting the images on the verso pages, and if so, how? It seems to me that atbegshi hooks up at too late a stage of processing.

Any hint is appreciated.

(*) [Document on recto page but numeration on both recto and verso](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216297)

Comment: one way is simply to typeset the text as one document and the images as another (with a small patch so the page numbers increase by 2 in each case) then use an external pdf tool to merge the two at the end

Comment: Right, that would be quite a straightforward way. Merging could be done with pdfpages.

Comment: I think this is already answered here for two different languages.
Using [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) package could be a solution.